# NPM - MYSQL - Passing query results to another variable

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm

I was looking for some help in regards to a database package that I'm building for a larger application. The application will essentially keep certain information on a database through the use of the mysql package in npm. The problem I'm facing is that when I try to pass the results variable to a variable that I've created I always get undefined. Though if I place a log statement underneath the variable transfer statement displaying the results variable it will be properly populated. I've done a fair amount of research and believe that this has something to do with promises and/or the callback function that's part of the query. I was wondering if I could have someone examine my code and let me know the best course of action. I've spent a couple of hours on this researching online and trying various solutions but nothing has worked.

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
var sqlResults;

var pool = mysql.createPool({
      host: "example.com",
      user: "exampleUser",
      password: "123456Password",
      database: "TestDB"
    }); 

module.exports = {

...

databaseSelect: function(table, fields, conditionalStmt) {
        pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
          if (err) 
            throw err;
          console.log("Connected to the example DB!");
          
          var sql = "SELECT " + fields + " FROM " + table + " " + conditionalStmt;
          
            connection.query(sql, function(error, results, fields) {
                console.log("Successfully retrieved records from " + table + "\n\t" + sql);
                sqlResults = results;
                connection.release();

                sqlResults = results;
                console.log(results);
                
                if (error) 
                    throw error;
            });
        });
        console.log(sqlResults);
        return sqlResults;
    }
}
```

Here's a sample of the output that I'm receiving:

```
I am ready!
undefined
undefined
Connected to the example DB!
Successfully retrieved records from User_Level_Info
        SELECT HashID, Level, Experience FROM User_Level_Info WHERE HashID = 'e578059cabc6f937f0219127384126143e272acbac52c331345d573e0f085d21'
[ RowDataPacket {
    HashID: 'e578059cabc6f937f0219127384126143e272acbac52c331345d573e0f085d21',
    Level: 1,
    Experience: 0 } ]
```

Comment: you will have to wait until you get result. Use Promise instead.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate more? Is there a reason async/await can't be used in this situation

Comment: I have converted it into a promise. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here convert it into a `Promise`.

So this will wait until it gets `resolved` or `reject`

```
databaseSelect: function(table, fields, conditionalStmt) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
          if (err) 
            return reject(err);
          console.log("Connected to the example DB!");
          
          var sql = "SELECT " + fields + " FROM " + table + " " + conditionalStmt;
          
            connection.query(sql, function(error, results, fields) {
                console.log("Successfully retrieved records from " + table + "\n\t" + sql);
                sqlResults = results;
                connection.release();

                sqlResults = results;
                console.log(results);
                
                if (error) 
                    return reject(error);
            });
        });

        resolve(sqlResults);
  });
}

//call your function
databaseSelect(params)
  .then(function(rows) {
    console.log(rows)
  })
  .catch((err) {
    console.log(err)
  }); // Throw async to escape the promise chain
```

Comment: I've tried to implement the solution and get the following error "missing ) after argument list" when I get to the catch. When I leave the catch statement as `.catch()` I get the following output `Promise { <pending> }`. Also I've asked how to pass the results to an external variable which this doesn't even touch. Your answer hasn't been anything close to helpful and some kind of explanation would've been great